# Bootstrap, replace Normalize with eric myer reset

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, reset

I have downloaded twitter  Bootstrap, the CSS includes Normalize css.

Is it possible to delete the  Normalize CSS and replace this with Eric Meyers reset? The reason I want to do this is  because

1) my li Nav menus seem to style a lot  better with the Eric Myers reset (is this because normalize handles UL li differently or just doesn't reset anything ?)

2) Eric Myer reset is neater / less lines of code / easier to read.

Will replacing Normalize cause any Bootstrap bugs, from my initial testing all seems to work?

Best 
P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can replace it. 
Actually both resets do almost the same.

But don't forget to use `.list-unstyled` class for lists you want to stay without dots.